# SQL: value equal to difference between a column in this row and another column in previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a timesheet dataset for which I only have the start time of the first of multiple activities for a staff member in a day, but I do have the qty minutes spent on each of the activities. I would like to generate a dataset that contains start and end times for each f the activities.

[image: Timesheet]

So the Start Time in row two must be = End Time in row one. End Time in Row two must be the newly calculated Start time for row two + Minutes in row two, and so on for the rest of the rows. I tried options of joining with the same table on t1.ActivityOrder = t2.ActivityOrder + 1 but this did not work.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: It's more useful to post sample data as text which we can use rather than images which we can't.

Comment: Noted, I will definitely do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no difference between end time of previous an start time of current you only need to know the start time of task order 1 and the cumulative durations

for example given

```
create table t
(id int,startdt smalldatetime, enddt smalldatetime, duration int, taskorder int);

insert into t values
(1,'2022-10-06 07:00:00',null, 20,1),
(2,null,null, 10,2),(3,null,null, 10,3),(4,null,null, 10,4)

select id, 
       case when startdt is null then
        dateadd(minute,sum(duration) over (order by taskorder ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 preceding ) ,
        (select startdt from t t1 where t1.taskorder = 1))
        else startdt
       end startdt,
       case when enddt is null then
        dateadd(minute,sum(duration) over(order by taskorder),
        (select startdt from t t1 where t1.taskorder = 1))
       end enddt,
      duration,
      taskorder,
      sum(duration) over (order by taskorder) sumtask,
      sum(duration) over (order by taskorder ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 preceding ) sumprecd
from t

id          startdt                 enddt                   duration    taskorder   sumtask     sumprecd
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2022-10-06 07:00:00     2022-10-06 07:20:00     20          1           20          NULL
2           2022-10-06 07:20:00     2022-10-06 07:30:00     10          2           30          20
3           2022-10-06 07:30:00     2022-10-06 07:40:00     10          3           40          30
4           2022-10-06 07:40:00     2022-10-06 07:50:00     10          4           50          40

(4 row(s) affected)
```